# Inserting data extracted from an XML file into a MySQL table

Tags: php, mysql, sql, arrays

I have a variety of data that I'm trying to export into an existing database table in MySQL.  Below is the PHP code that accesses the MySQL database and the XML document (edit.xml), extracts the necessary data and attempts to place it into the table, `Person`:

```
<?php

// create connection
$connect = mysqli_connect("localhost", "root", "****");
// check connection
if (!$connect) {
    die('Could not connect: ' . mysql_error());
    exit();
}

// select database
mysqli_select_db($connect, 'poeticarchive');

// save XML document as a variable reference
$xml = simplexml_load_file("edit.xml");

// search document for all <emph> elements with an attribute named 'altrender' that have the value 'identifier' (unique id value)
$aID = $xml -> xpath('//ead/archdesc/dsc/c01//c02[1]//@identifier');
// date of birth value
$dob = $xml -> xpath('//ead/archdesc/dsc/c01//c02[1]//emph[3]');
// first name value
$firstName = $xml -> xpath('//ead/archdesc/dsc/c01//c02[1]//emph[2]');
// last name value
$lastName = $xml -> xpath('//ead/archdesc/dsc/c01//c02[1]//emph[1]');
// biography value
$bio = $xml -> xpath('//ead/archdesc/dsc/c01/c02//c03/bioghist//p');
// books by author value
$book = $xml -> xpath('//ead/archdesc/dsc/c01/c02/c03/c04//unittitle | //ead/archdesc/dsc/c01/c02/c03/c04/c05//unittitle');

// store the values into an array
$person = array("AuthorID"=>$aID,
                "FirstName"=>$firstName,
                "LastName"=>$lastName,
                "Biography"=>$bio,
                "DateOfBirth"=>$dob,
                "Books"=>$book);

$personTable = implode("','",$person);

mysqli_query($connect, "INSERT INTO Person (AuthorID, FirstName, LastName, Biography, Books, DateOfBirth) VALUES ('$personTable')");

// close connection
mysqli_close($connect);

?>
```

This extracts the data I'm after (as I checked using `while(list($key $value) = each($array))` to display the data on-screen).  However it comes up with the error `Notice: Array to string conversion...`.  Does anyone know how I can iterate this array and insert the data into the table `Person`?

Thank you for your help!

Answer (score 0):

The error is clear enough.
SimpleXML returns values as array.

You can easily convert it to string using `(string) $xml->path()` though.

Comment: Thanks, tried replacing my `...$xml->xpath(...` section with this but just get more errors; where exactly should I be using `(string) $xml->path()`?

Comment: Try this : `$aID = (string) $xml -> xpath('//ead/archdesc/dsc/c01//c02[1]//@identifier');`. I don't use SimpleXML that way, but with the objects approach, but I assume its the same behavior

Comment: I get a `Notice: Array to string conversion` error for that line when I do that...

Comment: Well, try a `var_dump($xml->path(...))` on that line ? Otherwise, you could consider giving a try with the object approach of SimpleXML. Using it right now on a project, and I'm casting results to (string) as I said without any problem.

Answer (score 0):

you can try this,
instead of

```
mysqli_query($connect, "INSERT INTO Person (AuthorID, FirstName, LastName, Biography, Books, DateOfBirth) VALUES ('$personTable')");
```

write individual values in insert query
like this

```
mysqli_query($connect, "INSERT INTO Person (AuthorID, FirstName, LastName, Biography, Books, DateOfBirth) VALUES (" . $aID . ", '" . $firstName . "'" . $lastName . "'" . $bio . "'" . $dob . "'" . $book ."')");
```

Comment: Thanks but still get same error after I change this (`Notice: Array to string conversion in C:\xampp\htdocs\poetic_archive\connect.php on line 123`)

Comment: @jayrdi can you post line 123 from connect.php?

Comment: `$personTable = implode("','",$person);`

Comment: @jayrdi have you declared $personTable as an array?